# Splitting a Large S3 File into Lines per File (not bytes per file)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I have an 8 GB file with text lines (each line has a carriage return) in S3. This file is custom formatted and does NOT follow any common format like CSV, pipe, JSON ... 
I need to split that file into smaller files based on the number of lines, such that each file will contains 100,000 lines or less 
(assuming the last file can have the remainder of the lines and thus may have less than 100,000 lines).

1. I need a method that is not based on the file size (i.e. bytes), but the number of lines. Files can't have a single line split across the two.
2. I need to use Python.
3. I need to use server-less AWS service like Lambda, Glue ... I can't spin up instances like EC2 or EMR.

So far I found a lot of posts showing how to split by byte size but not by number of lines. 
Also, I do not want to read that file line by line as it will be just too slow an not efficient.

Could someone show me a starter code or method that could accomplish splitting this 6 GB file that would 
run fast and not require more than 10 GB of available memory (RAM), at any point?

I am looking for all possible options, as long as the basic requirements above are met...

BIG thank you!

Michael

Comment: I do not know the background how the file lands to S3. May be you can rethink if this could be done at the time of writing the file to S3. If it is sure that the processing is needed to be done post the writes, you can also choose to run AWS CodeBuild to do this job. Choice of language could be any Python, Bash, etc.

Comment: Thanks. There is no option to "re-think" at the time of writing to S3. Files are not written to S3 by me and I do not have control of when or how they are written (they are batch transferred by the process I do not control). This is why I clearly specified the basic requirements.

Comment: Can you tell us more about how the output files will be used? For example, will they be used in a Hadoop environment? If so, it might make sense to put the splitting process in the same environment. Also, how many files are there, and how often do they arrive?

Comment: What you request is not possible. The only way to process a file to break on particular lines is to read the contents of the files, yet you say "I do not want to read that file line by line". A system _needs_ to read line-by-line to achieve what you want. You say that it would be "slow and not efficient", but you don't say that speed is a particular requirement of your system. Why would the line-by-line approach not be acceptable for your solution? What speed would be acceptable?

Comment: Thank you for your questions! Is there a way in Python to instantly "jump" to a particular line in the file without reading each line before it? Suppose I have that 8 GB file loaded into a list, what would be the most efficient and quickest way to separate the first 100,000 lines (as elements) and write them to a file. Would you mind sharing a code snippet? The new smaller files will need to undergo a heavy transformation, which would be just too expensive to run on the original, single large file.

Answer (score 2):

`boto3.S3.Client.get_object()` method provides object of type `StreamingBody` as a response.

`StreamingBody.iter_lines()` method documentation states:

> Return an iterator to yield lines from the raw stream.
>
> This is achieved by reading chunk of bytes (of size chunk_size) at a
>   time from the raw stream, and then yielding lines from there.

This might suit your use case. General idea is to get that huge file streaming and process its contents as they come. I cannot think of a way to do this without reading the file in some way.

Comment: Thank you! Using this method, would you care to show a code snippet splitting a sample file line by line?

Comment: I'm afraid I will not be able to reproduce this, since it's very specific and not cost-free (storing several GB of data in personal S3 just for test)

Comment: Don't be afraid! I meant a sample file that is small. If you are fully competent at this code it would probably take minutes to write down. I can search and read the AWS docs myself. The crux is "interpreting" what's written there and implementing :) which is why I came for help here.